# How to match nodes with exactly matching properties in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher is there a way to match nodes exactly, i.e. match where the existing node contains only the properties queried for?
For example if we have the following nodes:

```
CREATE (n {field1: 'value1'})
CREATE (n {field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2'})
```

And match:

```
MATCH (n {field1: 'value1'}) RETURN (n)
```

This will return the both nodes. However, I want the second node to be excluded because it also contains field2 which is not in the set of queried properties

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the properties function, i.e.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE properties(n) = {field1: 'value1'} RETURN (n)
```

But would be good to know whether there are other/better ways